# rsync error did not see server greeting

Tags: linux, ssh, backup, rsync

I want to upload files using `rsync` over SSH.

On server side I have:

In `/root/.ssh/rsync.conf`:

```
uid = root
gid = root
use chroot = false

[data]
    path = /var/www/data
```

In `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` I have:

```
command="rsync --server --daemon --config rsync.conf ." ssh-rsa AAAAB3N...
```

On client side I have `ssh_config` file such as:

```
Host rsync_data
  User root
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  IdentityFile /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa_rsync
  ProxyCommand ssh eu -W 172.17.16.16:22
 
Host eu
 User me
 Port 4343
 Hostname My_Public_IP_Address_here
 IdentitiesOnly yes
 IdentityFile /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa_rsync
```

Finally, command getting launched is:

```
rsync \
 --delete \
 -avz \
 --stats \
 --progress \
 -e 'ssh -F /home/me/.ssh/config' \
 /home/me/Documents/dev/data/ rsync_data::data
```

SSH connection goes well as read in `/var/log/auth.log` but I get this rsync error:

```
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at clientserver.c(1223 [Receiver=3.2.3]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(231) [sender=3.2.7]
```

How can I solve the issue I am encountering?

Comment: Why did you configure anything with `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` or `/root/.ssh/rsync.conf`? Whenever I do Rsync the most I have to do is just add `id_rsa.pub` and then just do a plain Rsync without something like what you have here: `-e 'ssh -F /home/me/.ssh/config'`. My initial thoughts is you are making this more complex than need be.

Comment: I want to contrain client to only upload into a specific folder enforced by server in ``rsync.conf`. Is there another way to do it ? Also if i only add SSH keys into ``/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`` then anyone having access to client can directly get shell on server (as root!) where with this configuration, all an attacker can do is uploading wrong content that may be easier to dissmiss

Comment: Look up chroot jails. Look at this thread on the [Unix Stack Exchange site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/105/30848) that explains them. But also realize that you might overthinking this all. Why not set up a non pro ledges user on the destination server to SSH/Rsync content to and use that user for file transmission. Remember the `root` user n the destination server can access any file from any user. Why risk anything by using `root` to transmit files? Create a new user, allow that user limited access to the destination directory and that’s that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I got it.

Only thing I was missing is that daemon is looking for `rsync.conf` in user home directory or in `/etc/rsync.conf` if user is root.

This answer on Server Fault made my day : [solution](https://serverfault.com/a/7512/92146).

Comment: Cool! Just one relatively small suggestion: Using one backtick (`\``) is good for inline code and three backticks (`\`\`\``) are good for code blocks, but you seem to be consistently setting two backticks (`\`\``) which do nothing special at best or break formatting at worst. Look at how [your comment here](https://superuser.com/questions/1759880/rsync-error-did-not-see-server-greeting?noredirect=1#comment2735771_1759880) is broken due to that. Please just use one backtick (`\``) for inline code formatting.